# How to choose set in Group Isomorphism Algorithm( Quasipolynomial time)

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, finite-groups, computer-science, group-isomorphism

In the paper titled  "On the $n^{log_2(n)}$ Isomorphism Technique" by Gary L. Miller, it is written

> A group is a binary operation * ,  satisfying 1) and 2) .
>
> 1)
>   a)$ \exists! x(a*b = x)$
>
> b) $\exists! x(a*x = b)$
>
> c) $ \exists! x(x*a = b)$
>
> 2) $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$
>
> Theorem 1: Quasigroup isomorphism can be solved in $O(n^{log_2(n) +
> > 0(1)})$ steps.
>
> Proof: Property 1a) says the binary operation is a well-defined
>   function. Now, 1b) and 1c) give two other well-defined functions
>   associated with a quasigroup. We shall say that a set of elements
>   generates the quasigroup if  their closure under these three functions
>   is the whole quasigroup.Thus, using this  definition, we prove a
>   generalization(Lemma 1) of the observation about the size of the
>   minimal generator set.
>
> Lemma 1: A quasigroup is generated by a set containing at most $log_2(n)$ elements.
>
> To finish the proof of Theorem 1 we give a short description of the
>   algorithm with two quasigroups, $G$ and $G'$, as input:
>
> 1) Find a set of generators for $G$, containing at most $log_2(n)$ elements, 
>   say,  $a_1,···,a_m$.
>
> 2) For each set of $m$ elements in $G'$, say, $\{b_1 ,···,b_m \}$
>   check to see if the map induced by $a_i \mapsto b_i , 1\leq i\leq m$ is
>   a well-defined isomorphism of $G$ onto $G'$
>
> 3) If a set of $m$ elements
>   of $G'$  is found in 2) accept;otherwise reject.

I could not understand-

> 2) For each set of $m$ elements in $G'$, say, $\{b_1 ,···,b_m \}$
>   check to see if the map induced by $a_i \mapsto b_i , 1\leq i\leq m$ is
>   a well-defined isomorphism of $G$ onto $G'$

I can choose ${n}\choose{m} $ different  set, each having $m$ elements where order does not matter. In that case,  the problem can't be solved  in $O(n^{log_2(n) + 0(1)})$ steps.

So, how "each set of $m$ elements in $G'$, say, $\{b_1 ,···,b_m \}$
 check to see if the map induced by $a_i \mapsto b_i , 1\leq i\leq m$ is
a well-defined isomorphism of $G$ onto $G'$ " gives a Quasipoloynomial Algorithm?
To be precise, how I choose  "each set of $m$ elements" ?

Comment: I don't see the problem. The number of choices of $b_1,\ldots,b_m$ is at most $n^m \le n^{\log_2 n}$. For a given choice of the $b_i$, checking that the map defined is an isomorphism can be done in time polynomial in $n$.

Comment: By the way, the wording of 2) is very poor. It should be for each ordered set (or sequence)  of $m$ eleemnts, not for each set of $m$ elements.

Comment: @DerekHolt  and I am a novice who started reading these literature! :( .  I am trying to understand your comment, ...  'll ping you, if  I fail.

Comment: Proving that you can check (for given $b_i$) whether the map $\phi$  defined is aan isomorphism in polynomial time is not totally easy! You have to start by using the generators $a_i$ to generate all of the other elements of $G$. You can then perform the corresponding operations on the $b_i$ to find the images of these elements under $\phi$. These shoudl all be distinct, since otherwise $\phi$ would not be an isomorphism. Then you can check whether $\phi(a*b)=\phi(a)*\phi(b)$ for all $a,b \in G$. All of these calculations can be done in tiem polynomial in $|G|$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Assume, the generating set has $2$ elements. How many ways $2$ elements can be choosen from a set of  $n$ elements               where 1) Order matters  and 2) repetition is allowed ?                                For example, geven a set of $n$ elements, how many ordered pairs would there be  in the form of $(a,b)$  Answer: One can fill the first slot(the place of $a$) in $n$ ways, and second slot(the place of $b$)  also in $n$ ways since repetion is allowed. So, $n^2= n^m \leq n^{log_2(n)}$. Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct, although there is no point in having repeated generators, so you could make it $n(n-1)$.